# More efficient way to evaluate overlap of a key-value list (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list (csv) of 1M rows like this:

```
Keyword,URL

Word1,URL1
Word1,URL2
..
Word1,URL100
Word2,URL4
Word1,URL101,
..
Word10000,URLN
```

So I have 10,000 keywords with 100 URLs for each keyword. Each URL could be related to one or more keyword(s).

I need to obtain a Pandas dataframe (or a csv), like this:

```
Keyword1,Keyword2,Weight
Word1,Word2,5
Word1,Word3,6
```

Where the weight is the number of equal URLs for each pair of keywords I found. So I the example I suppose "Word1" and "Word2" have 5 shared URLs.

I used Pandas and I done a nested iteration over dataframes, but I need a more efficient way to do that, assuming that a nested iteration is not the best way to perform this task.

```py
for index, row in keylist.iterrows():
    keyurlcompare = keyurl[keyurl['Keyword'] == row['Keyword']]
    idx1 = pd.Index(keyurlcompare['URL'])

# Second iterations

    for index2, row2 in keylist.iterrows():
        keyurlcompare2 = keyurl[keyurl['Keyword'] == row2['Keyword']]
        idx2 = pd.Index(keyurlcompare2['URL'])
        # Intersection evaluation
        interesectw = idx1.intersection(idx2)
        we = len(interesectw)
        if we > 0 and row['Keyword'] != row2['Keyword']:
            df1 = pd.DataFrame([[row['Keyword'],row2['Keyword'],we]],columns=['Source', 'Target', 'Weight'])
            df = df.append(df1)
            print('Keyword n. ' + str(index) + ' (' + row['Keyword']  + ') con Keyword n. ' +  str(index2) + ' (' + row2['Keyword'] +') - Intersect: ' + str(we))
```

It works and I print this kind of output:

```
Keyword n. 0 (word1) with Keyword n. 9908 (word2) - Intersect: 1
Keyword n. 0 (word1) with Keyword n. 10063 (word3) - Intersect: 12
Keyword n. 0 (word1) con Keyword n. 10064 (word4) - Intersect: 1
```

But it's obviously incredibly slow. Could you help me in finding a more efficient way to perform this task?

Comment: How many different URLs have you? And how many available memory?

Comment: I have around 400.000 differenti URLs. I'm actually using my laptop (16GB RAM)

Comment: It could be improved by pre-calculating a pivot table with URLs in rows and keywords in columns, but with so large data, memory errors are to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to reverse the processing:

1. find all keywords per URL
2. build a dataframe giving per URL all keyword pairs
3. sum the number of occurences per pair

Code could be:

```
detail = df.groupby('URL').apply(
    lambda z: pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(z.Keyword,2)),
                           columns=['Keyword1', 'Keyword2']))

result = detail.reset_index(level=0).groupby(
    ['Keyword1', 'Keyword2']).count().rename({'URL': 'Weight'}).reset_index()
```

The `result` dataframe should be what you want

Detail is rather expensive to obtain with large data, several minutes on a decent machine for the magnitude order of data size you gave, result is much quicker. But at least there should be no memory error with a machine having more than 12 GB RAM